# How to format the number .00 to 0.00?

Tags: java, format

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##,###.00");  
String str = nf.format(0);  
System.out.println(str);
```

If the num is not 0, the result is right.
but when num is 0,the result is .00,
How to make the result to 0.00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this number format instead:

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##,##0.00");  
                                          ^
                                          |
```